# is 1.8mb bad or good for Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

[Webpack bundle size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDaTF.png)

The title pretty much explains it all. I was working on my application and noticed my Webpack bundle was 1.8mb. IDK if that's normal or bad because I assume most of the space is from node_modules

Comment: It's bigger than 1.7, but smaller than 1.9. What are you expecting to hear?

Comment: http://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/

Comment: I mean. I was expecting a yes or no answer as the question implies and not a sarcastic answer but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends.**

With proper caching and an adequate download speed, your users may only download this file once and then their experience is snappy and fast the rest of the time.

There are ways to reduce the size of your bundle if needed (code splitting with async loading of components/resources, removing dead code, removing complex dependencies, reducing bloat, minifying JS, reducing polyfills, etc.).

[Code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) can be a great way to defer the loading of resources that aren't immediately needed.  This will reduce your Webpack bundle size.  Combined with proper caching, your user's experience will remain fast.

If you need to see what is included in your bundle, use the [Webpack Bundle Visualizer](http://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/).